# What does "run down leads" mean?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I stumbled on a post on a different forum by a native speaker who was explaining what the phrase "***run down leads***" mean in police work. The problem is that when I googled the phrase the definition I found for it disagrees with his explanation. The user said:

1. "*billmcd: It means to follow up on apparently valuable information (tips) provided by persons or based on evidence related to a crime.*"

This is the definition for "*run down*" that I found:

2. to search out;
   find:[~ + down + object]
   *to run down some leads in the murder case.
   to run some leads down.*(Random House Learner's Dictionary of American English © 2024)

Does "*run down leads*" mean to "*follow up on the information in a case*" or to "*find information that can help you solve the case*"?

Comment: They both mean *investigate the leads further*.

Comment: You have your answer from the dictionary. Tell me how you think it could mean something else. What that other forum post said and what the dictionary said are the same thing.

Comment: @Lambie It's because as a person learning mostly from movies and books I tought "follow up on" only means "to do something in addition to what you have already done in order to make it more likely to succeed (Longman dictionary). I even know in which movie I've heard this phrase for the first time. It was "The Silence of the Lambs" (although it was in the noun form there) "it's just a routine follow-up". In this case it was a second interview with Hannibal Lecter by agent Starling.
.....

Comment: I failed to realize that "follow up on" has the additional meaning of  "investiage something further". What is annoying though is that even for this meaning there is a sample sentence that talks about calling someone on the phone (just like in the sample-sentence for a different meaning from Longman Dictionary).                                    
(Oxford Languages): follow up: pursue or investigate something further.
"I decided to follow up the letters with phone calls" (Oxford Languagages). These are two dictinct meanings though right?

Comment: When you encounter seemingly conflicting definitions, using additional dictionaries (especially ones not specifically for learners) can help. [to find someone or something after following or searching for him, her, or it for a long time](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/run-down)

Comment: to run down means to follow here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does mean those things:  "Follow up information in a case with the intention of finding additional information that can help you solve the case"  Normally there isn't any need to add "with the intention of finding additional information that can help you solve the case"  It can be assumed that everything that a police officer does while working a case is intended to help solve it